# Getting public key using the generated certificate(X509) using CertificateFactory

Tags: java, x509certificate

I am having trouble getting the public Key using the X509 certificate. I am getting an error "signed fields invalid" when trying to generate certification. Please help

**Code used to generate the key:**

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey() throws CertificateException,FileNotFoundException {

    InputStream certFileIs = new FileInputStream("E:\\TA_Private.pfx");
    CertificateFactory certfactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certfactory.generateCertificate(certFileIs);
    PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();
    return key;
}
```

Console output:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1768)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:196)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at Keygenerator.getPublicKey(Keygenerator.java:45)
    at KeyMain.main(KeyMain.java:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing of file fails. Actually, since your file is named TA_Private.pfx, it makes me think that this file is not a X509 certificate but a [PKCS#12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) file (i.e. a file which can contain both keys and certificates and is used for exchange of secret material between systems)

To read a PKCS#12 file you can use the `KeyStore` class:

```
public PublicKey loadPKCS#12(String filePath, char[] password) throws Exception {
  InputStream is = null;
  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
  try {
    is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    ks.load(is, password);
    for (Enumeration<String> e = ks.aliases(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
      String alias = e.nextElement();
      if (ks.isCertificateEntry(alias)) {
        Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);
        return cert.getPublicKey();
      }
    }
    return null;
  } finally {
    if (is != null) {
      is.close();
    }
  }
}
```

This is a really simple example which extracts the public key of the first found certificate. However a PKCS#12 can contains multiple certificates.

Comment: Why does it return false for the aliases when quering for isCertificateEntry(alias); please give an explaination.Thank u..

Comment: a KeyStore is a generic container. It can contains certificate but also keys. When iterating over all aliases you need to check the type of object stored under this alias.

Comment: But in my case when i am printing the alias obtained i found that i have two alias and they both are same(alphanumeric values). And if i put that check say isCertificate i am not able to get the key coz its returning false. And so i removed the if check and checked it i am getting some values and when i retrieve key.getEncoded() i get some 294 bytes. Then what is this 294 bytes representing...

Comment: And also according to ur explanation i get to know that my alias is not a certificate object. So is my file or is my keystore type wrong(the parameter of getInstance(keystore type)).